# Angular 13: Disable aot when running ng-serve

Tags: angular

AOT is on by default since Angular 9, I tried to run in JIT mode by adding the option "--aot=false" that throws error "Unknown option --aot". In angular.json file, I tried to add `"aot": false` under `"serve: options"`, but this gives warning "property aot is not allowed". How can I disable AOT by default when running ng serve only? This is my angular.json file:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/ProjectName",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/global-styles/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "WebUINext:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "WebUINext:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
          // No aot property allowed here
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @skyBlue I guess JIT is more convenient for development, faster building project and easier to debug in the right components, instead of main.js.

Comment: go to https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler and search for: *Here are some reasons you might want to use AOT*

Comment: @skyBlue I read a bunch of stuffs including this article before posting this question, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Hey @Hoàng Nguyễn, I think I found it, check it out

Comment: @HarisBouchlis I don't think this is right as I needed. As far as I know, everything under `build` should works only for `ng build`, your updated answer is configured for development environment when running `ng build` and this has nothing to do with `ng serve`. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option in `build.configutations` in `angular.json`

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "configurations": {
         "development": {
           "aot": false,
           "buildOptimizer": false
           ...
         },
         ...
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
```

Comment: I think this is only for ng build. I need for ng serve.

Comment: yes it will do the job but for builds they must switch every time. so this is not the right way. @HoàngNguyễn

Comment: `but for builds they must switch every time` You normally will build for production using ng build which will not be affected at all. So this here should be the accepted answer. You  will be affected only on build for development or ng serve which is what you have required